# maximum concurrent count record in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

how to find the maximum concurrent connected client count on the basis of networkId filed in 1 hour in elasticsearch?

I have tried this 1 query

GET /sample_index/_search {"size":0,"query":{"bool":{"range":{"@timestamp":{"gte":"now-1h","lt":"now"}}}},"aggregations":{"maxconnectclient":{"terms":{"field":"networkId.keyword","size":10},"aggregations":{"wlan0clintCount":{"sum":{"field":"wlan0.clients"}},"wlan1clintCount":{"sum":{"field":"wlan1.clients"}},"totalClientCount":{"bucket_script":{"buckets_path":{"wlan0clintCount":"wlan0clintCount","wlan1clintCount":"wlan1clintCount"},"script":{"source":"double sum = 0.0; sum = params.wlan0clintCount + params.wlan1clintCount+p; return (sum);","lang":"painless"}}}}}}}

and found the only all-max record of   1hours

or should i use this query---
GET sample _index/_search
{"size":0,"query":{"bool":{"filter":[{"range":{"@timestamp":{"gte":"now-1h","lt":"now"}}}]}},"aggregations":{"maxconnectclient":{"terms":{"field":"networkId.keyword","size":10,"min_doc_count":1,"shard_min_doc_count":0,"show_term_doc_count_error":false,"order":[{"_count":"desc"},{"_key":"asc"}]},"aggregations":{"wlan0clintCount":{"sum":{"field":"wlan0.clients"}},"wlan1clintCount":{"sum":{"field":"wlan1.clients"}},"wlan2clintCount":{"sum":{"field":"wlan2.clients"}},"wlan2_6clintCount":{"sum":{"field":"wlan2_6.clients"}},"totalClientCount":{"bucket_script":{"buckets_path":{"wlan0clintCount":"wlan0clintCount","wlan1clintCount":"wlan1clintCount","wlan2clintCount":"wlan2clintCount","wlan2_6clintCount":"wlan2_6clintCount"},"script":{"source":"double sum = 0.0; sum = params.wlan0clintCount + params.wlan1clintCount+params.wlan2clintCount+params.wlan2_6clintCount; return (sum);","lang":"painless"},"gap_policy":"skip"}},"sum_bucket_sort":{"bucket_sort":{"sort":[{"totalClientCount":{"order":"desc"}}],"from":0,"gap_policy":"SKIP"}}}}}}

Comment: and result we are getting only max-conncurrent client in 1 hour,    How to get the max-connurrent client in 1 hour?????????????

Comment: Please share an example of sample query to get the result